# Security exception by accessing the wifi in android

Tags: android, wifi

Please see the following code

```
    wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
```

Though I have added the permission in manifest file as

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.wifi"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

but still it is giving following error

```
   11-23 15:18:24.399: E/AndroidRuntime(6800): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.wifi/com.test.wifi.WifiDemoActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10082 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
```

Please help why this is happening

Answer (score 18):

To be able to access the wifi you need android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" as  you already know.

If you are enabling or disabling the wifi connection you are also going to need both permissions: ACCESS_WIFI_STATE and CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

That should do it for you.

Answer (score 5):

add following lines

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

hope they help!

Answer (score 3):

It should be "uses-permission" rather than "user-permission". spelling is wrong

Comment: Do a project clean, and then a build.

Comment: Your manifest has to look like this http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SipDemo/AndroidManifest.html

Comment: 11-23 15:36:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1677): java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10082 nor current process has android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE.

Comment: Are you trying it in device or emulator? does it work in device?