# java.lang.Securityexception when checking Wifi

Tags: android, android-wifi

```
private void requestNewCoordinates() {          

        final WifiManager wfManager = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
             if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
                && wfManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
             }
}

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

when `wfManager.isWifiEnabled()  - java.lang.Securityexception`

Tell me what's wrong .. and how to solve the problem

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9325388/1568164  - it works

Comment: Did you include needed permissions in the manifest XML file?

Comment: Are you sure that your device having Wifi first?

Comment: Now it is connected to WIFI network

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9325388/1568164

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this permissions in your manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have declared in the manifest file the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission.

Answer (score 0):

Give permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```