# Android user permission error (android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE)

Tags: java, android

I have an error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10132 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
```

I try do get wifi name (ssid). I use this code:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
System.out.println(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo ().getSSID ());
```

In my manifest file i added this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

What i do wrong? 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240561/security-exception-by-accessing-the-wifi-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531940/how-to-get-name-of-wifi-network-out-of-android-using-android-api) doesn't work for me
Thanks

My full logcat:

```
10-09 16:08:23.705  31988-31988/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10132 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10132 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
            at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.getConnectionInfo(IWifiManager.java:991)
            at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.getConnectionInfo(WifiManager.java:976)
            at com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity$PlanetFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:261)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5335)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check Spelling only or remove that permission and copy paste it again from deve site, error comes when we did spell mistakes. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" /> Or check your manifest thoroughly. Good luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking into account that you're using the right permission and the lines are syntactically correct, it's likely you've **misplaced the permissions in your manifest**, if you have them somewhere else but the root of the manifest xml node, they will likely not work at all. They need to go **after** `<manifest>` **and before** `</manifest>` but not inside `<application>` or `<activity>`

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
 ...YOUR APPLICATION & ACTIVITY HERE...
</manifest>
```

*Note that the manifest tag was simplified for readability*

[<uses-permission>](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)

Comment: Yep, you are right. I've this permessions into <application</application>

Comment: Glad you figured it out ;)

Answer (score -2):

add this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

it is Ok for me!

Answer (score -2):

```
if(provider!=null && !provider.equals("")){

    // Get the location from the given provider
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);   // error (call require permission which may be rejected by user)

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 1, this);

    if(location!=null)
        onLocationChanged(location);
    else
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

when you change wifi state, this also need this.

try this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Add this list of permission in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: what? explain please more detail

Comment: add this in your manifest file
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

Comment: i used only this permission..<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62760/discussion-between-harikrishnan-and-user2051503).